# C++ Encoding Decoding

Tags: c++

//
/*Example for the message: "hello" and a shift of 1. The encryptor shifts every letter up by one: h -> i, e -> f, l -> m, l -> m, o -> p.
So encrypt("hello") returns "ifmmp". The decrypt function does the opposite, so decrypt("ifmmp") return "hello".
The cypher encryptor uses a string that represents the letter transformation as a way to encrypt decrypt.
So an ecryptor with the cypher: "efyhadwzlvjnktbogrumcpiqxs" encrypts a -> e, b -> f, c -> y, d -> h and so on.
With this encryptor, encrypt("hello") returns "zannb", and decrypt("zannb") returns "hello"*/

***I am getting as a result when I run the code:***

```
shift encode result == ifmmpaxpsme
shift encode result == jhoor  ruog
encryptor encode result == c bj aiuw
encryptor encode result == kdedkuerldcqoepujoevlnrewurrjeu
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class encryptor
{
public:
    virtual string encode(string original) = 0;
    virtual string decode(string secret) = 0;
};

class shift_encryptor : public encryptor
{
    int shift;

public:
    shift_encryptor(int shift)
    {
        // Your code starts here
        this->shift = shift;
        // Your code ends here
    }

    string encode(string original)
    {
        // Your code starts here 
        char c_original[26] = { ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
        string original_result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
        {
            int c_index = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(c_original); j++)
            {
                if (original[i] == c_original[j])
                {
                    c_index = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            int final_index = c_index + this->shift;
            if (final_index > sizeof(c_original) - 1)
                final_index -= sizeof(c_original);
            original_result += c_original[final_index];
        }
        return original_result;
        // Your code ends here
    }

    string decode(string secret)
    {
        // Your code starts here 
        char c_secret[26] = { ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
        string secret_result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++)
        {
            int c_index = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(c_secret); j++)
            {
                if (secret[i] == c_secret[j])
                {
                    c_index = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            int final_index = c_index - this->shift;
            if (final_index < 0)
                final_index += sizeof(c_secret);
            secret_result += c_secret[final_index];
        }
        return secret_result;
        // Your code ends here
    }
};

class cypher_encryptor : public encryptor
{
    string cypher;
public:
    cypher_encryptor(string cypher)
    {
        // Your code starts here
        this->cypher = cypher;
        // Your code ends here
    }
    string encode(string original)
    {
        // Your code starts here 
        char c_original[26] = { ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
        string original_result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
        {
            int c_index = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < this->cypher.length(); j++)
            {
                if (original[i] == this->cypher[j])
                {
                    c_index = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            original_result += c_original[c_index];
        }
        return original_result;
        // Your code ends here
    }

    string decode(string secret)
    {
        // Your code starts here
        char c_secret[26] = { ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
        string secret_result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++)
        {
            int c_index = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(c_secret); j++)
            {
                if (secret[i] == c_secret[j])
                {
                    c_index = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            secret_result += this->cypher[c_index];
        }
        return secret_result;
        // Your code ends here
    }
};

//After

int main()
{
    shift_encryptor* shiftTest = new shift_encryptor(1);
    string encodeResult = "";
    string decodeResult = "";

    encodeResult = shiftTest->encode("hello world");
    cout << "shift encode result == " << encodeResult << endl;

    decodeResult = shiftTest->decode("lipps${svph");
    cout << "shift encode result == " << decodeResult << endl;

    // string encodeResult = shiftTest->en

    cypher_encryptor* crypterTest = new cypher_encryptor("efyhadwzlvjnktbogrumcpiqxs");

    encodeResult = crypterTest->encode("heyj fvmpe");
    cout << "encryptor encode result == " << encodeResult << endl;
    decodeResult = crypterTest->decode("me emt shevyp wtjp ihls ftssjkt");
    cout << "encryptor decode result == " << decodeResult << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated, with the interfaces and whatnot.

Comment: Why even judge code that could be educational this way. If I wanted to learned interfaces for example, or practice them, I wouldn't build a whole project that justifies them, I would just use them in something way, way too trivial for them. Yet people think that just because you do it in your practice or educational code, that you don't know it would be an overkill in commercial code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this a special requirement, or do you just dislike the letter `k`? ;)

Comment: It supposed to print out like tin the example with the "hello"

Comment: In case my previous comment wasn't understodd as intended: The lists of characters are missing the letter `k`. But you still need to ask a question. And you might want to split the program in two, to debug, validate and ask about each implementation of `encryptor` seperately, to narrow doen the focus of your question.

Comment: @szpanczyk It is possible to find a project that is both small enough for to highlight the principle at hand, and justifies the use. When the use is not justified, a lot of people will end up thinking the principle itself is pointless. As an example, a Pet interface with a pure virtual speak function. Derive a dog, cat, mouse, and bird class. Place one of each pet in a vector and have them all speak. It's small, and it justifies the use. You could then use this same project to learn about the factory pattern. What you are attempting to justify is pointless busy work.

Comment: At least, that's exactly how I showcased virtual functions when I lectured about them. It can be done from scratch, during a lecture, while picking hilarious pet names with the students.

Comment: @sweenish Well, I still don't think that making a project that justifies the use of feature is actually combining properly method with goal. If goal is to learn how a feature works, you make a minimal case or small case as that makes some difference in your observations. This is reaching your goal with least effort - goal is to understand the feature. I don't learn feature to know what it works for, I learn it to know how to deploy it, I usually already know why I want to learn it. 

Anyway, what you just wrote about, is exactly a small example I'm talking about.

Comment: @sweenish I've had larger codebases accused of overengineering and such, when the purpose was to show that I know how to properly use certain language features.I find this kind of observation pointless, especially since if I create a project myself, I always err heavily on the long-term maintainability. People might just have a skewed perspective, I want my code to be possibly powerful, so whenever I decide it needs some expansion, it should be very easy to expand. It calls for bigger work upfront.

Comment: You do you, then. Some features don't make sense without justified use. Like pointers. I use one lecture to demonstrate syntax and the idea of de-referencing and whatnot. Students come out of that lecture thinking pointers are just variables with extra steps. It's not until you `new` something and demonstrate a made-to-order array that they start to actually care. You're acting like "the principle" is all that matters, and that finding appropriate projects for learning is difficult. Both are bad assumptions. You could be learning better than you are now.

Comment: I never said to do think that don't make sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't bother stating what your expected output is supposed to be. One thing it looks like you're not doing is taking non-alphabetic characters into consideration. Are you supposed to encode all characters or just letters? If it's all characters, your approach is extremely wrong instead of kind of wrong. This answer assumes that only letters are to be encoded/decoded.

But here are a couple errors:

- `sizeof(c_original)` is probably supposed to be `c_original.length()`
- Your shift algorithm doesn't use the `shift` variable, and instead hardcodes a shift of 1 while **leaving out** the letter 'k'.
- Your shift decode appears to just further encode, instead of shifting back the other way (I didn't run it, but the code is too identical, i.e., I'm not seeing differences where I feel like I should be)
- You don't test your cypher class with the same message in the problem statement; how do you know if it's working or not?

As my comments indicate, I don't believe this to be a great example of polymorphism as-is. But one small change to the layout can make it a better example. The change is to actually rely on polymorphism, in this case with a free function that demonstrates the encode/decode with any derived-from-Encryption object.

Your code is a classic case of over-thinking things. There might also be some unawareness of ASCII. My code will assume ASCII, which seems safe given the code you have written.

First, some better best practices. Your constructors do not utilize the initialization section. Class names *should* start with a capital letter. Use the `override` specifier when overriding virtual functions. `using namespace std;` is bad practice. Especially in an example like this one that would typically be spread across multiple files. Don't put that baggage on users of your classes. The extra typing is hardly that bad, and you could always include specific using statements if you wanted.

Now, your interface. It needs a virtual destructor. When dealing with polymorphism, any non-concrete class still needs a destructor, and it must be virtual. You should have gotten warnings if you at least had `-Wall -Wextra` turned on. If you aren't enabling warnings, your behavior needs to change. Give yourself the help that is freely available to you.

```cpp
class Encryption {
public:
  virtual ~Encryption() = default;  // needed
  virtual void encrypt(std::string& message) = 0;
  virtual void decrypt(std::string& message) = 0;
};
```

I have also changed the functions a bit to take the strings by reference. This just has to do with encryption/decryption practices. Encrypting communications should mean encrypting communications, and **not** encrypting copies of communications.

A couple quick notes on character manipulation:

- If I have `char letter = 'a';`, I can do basic arithmetic on that character to change its value. This means that `++letter;` now makes `letter` hold the value `'b'`. Refer to an ASCII table.
- For basic ASCII work, `<cctype>` will be your friend.

Those notes should help with the shift encryption and simplify things quite a bit:

```cpp
class ShiftEncryption : public Encryption {
  int m_shift;
public:
  ShiftEncryption(int shift) : Encryption(), m_shift(shift) {}

  void encrypt(std::string& message) override
  {
    for (auto& i : message) {
      if (std::isalpha(i)) {
        i = std::toupper(i);
        i += m_shift;
        if (i > 'Z') {
          i -= 26;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void decrypt(std::string& message) override
  {
    for (auto& i : message) {
      if (std::isalpha(i)) {
        i -= m_shift;
        if (i < 'A') {
          i += 26;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

All you have to do is literally add or subtract the shift, and just use a quick check to wrap around again when needed. I use `std::isalpha()` because this code only cares about the roman alphabet (assumed from the code you've written).

My cypher encryption:

```cpp
class CypherEncryption : public Encryption {
  std::string m_cyperAlphabet;
  std::string_view m_alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
public:
  CypherEncryption(std::string alphabet)
      : m_cyperAlphabet([&alphabet]() {
          std::transform(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), alphabet.begin(),
                         [](char c) { return std::toupper(c); });
          return alphabet;
        }()) {}

  void encrypt(std::string& message) override {
    for (auto& i : message) {
      if (std::isalpha(i)) {
        i = std::toupper(i);
        i = m_cyperAlphabet[m_alphabet.find(i)];
      }
    }
  }

  void decrypt(std::string& message) override {
    for (auto& i : message) {
      if (std::isalpha(i)) {
        i = m_alphabet[m_cyperAlphabet.find(i)];
      }
    }
  }
};
```

My code is smaller because I take advantage of the functionality that the `std::string` class provides. It also helps to know that a `std::string` object can still be thought of as an array of characters.
NOTE: I also went nuts on the constructor as a copy/paste prevention.

I'll take a moment here to explain why I capitalize everything. First, it makes things easier if all letters are the same case. This code would be a lot bigger if I had to deal with upper and lower case letter separately. Second, and this is a very small point in comparison, it can be argued that simple substitution cyphers gain just a little bit more security from all letters being the same case. Think recognizing a proper name through a capital letter, which immediately gives adversaries an extra hint. Modern digital encryption schemes deal with the bits directly, so it's not a concern in the "real world."

Now, we get to what spurred my original comments. Your main function does not do anything polymorphic. You go through the steps, with heap-allocated encryptions, but then you don't actually utilize polymorphism. We're going to change that by writing a free function to demonstrate the encryption engines.

```cpp
void demonstrate(std::string message, Encryption& engine)
{
  std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::left << "Original: " << message << '\n';
  engine.encrypt(message);
  std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::left << "Encoded: " << message << '\n';
  engine.decrypt(message);
  std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::left << "Decoded: " << message << "\n\n";
}
```

Note the second parameter. It's a reference to an Encryption, which is my abstract base class. It is through pointers or references to the **base** class that we get polymorphism.

I take the message by value in order to preserve it in `main()` for re-use.

And now with that function, the main function is simplified quite a bit:

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::string firstMessage("Hello World");
  std::string secondMessage("Zipper");

  ShiftEncryption byOne(1);
  ShiftEncryption byTen(10);

  std::cout << "Shift by 1:\n";
  demonstrate(firstMessage, byOne);
  demonstrate(secondMessage, byOne);
  std::cout << "Shift by 10:\n";
  demonstrate(firstMessage, byTen);
  demonstrate(secondMessage, byTen);

  std::cout << "Provided cypher:\n";
  CypherEncryption cypher("efyhadwzlvjnktbogrumcpiqxs");
  demonstrate(firstMessage, cypher);

  std::cout << "'Unknown' cypher:\n";
  std::string alphabet("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
  std::shuffle(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));
  CypherEncryption oneTimePad(alphabet);
  demonstrate(firstMessage, oneTimePad);
}
```

The output:

```
Shift by 1:
Original: Hello World
Encoded:  IFMMP XPSME
Decoded:  HELLO WORLD

Original: Zipper
Encoded:  AJQQFS
Decoded:  ZIPPER

Shift by 10:
Original: Hello World
Encoded:  ROVVY GYBVN
Decoded:  HELLO WORLD

Original: Zipper
Encoded:  JSZZOB
Decoded:  ZIPPER

Provided cypher:
Original: Hello World
Encoded:  ZANNB IBRNH
Decoded:  HELLO WORLD

'Unknown' cypher:
Original: Hello World
Encoded:  CHLLG AGVLK
Decoded:  HELLO WORLD
```

Note that I did *not* need to allocate the `ShiftEncryption` or `CypherEncryption` on the heap (I didn't `new` anything). It simply wasn't necessary for this example. The one time pad at the end of the output will be different every run because the cypher key is randomly generated on each run.

If this is a homework, congratulations, it's been done for you.